# LIBGDX: NPE error trace and instantiation

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've been encountering `nullPointerException` in my program, but the variable vector which is being used is instantiated and also set in a method. the problem is that we tried tracing the problem to its root, and still no answer to our problem why its getting null.

Code:

```
static class AI {
    private String log = AI.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean lock = false , placed = false , moving = false , 
            chasing = true, drop = false, decision = false;
    private float counter, x, y;
    private int xDir, yDir;
    private DugMan d;
    private Enemy e;

    public void Checker() {
        if (chasing) {
            e.ePosition.x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*x;
            e.ePosition.y += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*y;
        }

        if (moving) {Gdx.app.log(log, Integer.toString(xDir, yDir));}
        if (chasing) {Gdx.app.log(log, Float.toString(counter));}
        if (counter > 0) {counter--;}

        if (e.ePosition.y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 10) {
            e.ePosition.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 10;
        }
        if (e.ePosition.y <= 0) {
            e.ePosition.y = 1;
        }
        if (e.ePosition.x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 10) {
            e.ePosition.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 10;
        }
        if (e.ePosition.x <= 0) {
            e.ePosition.x = 1;
        }
    }

    public int chooseRandomDirection() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] randDirection = new int[3];
    randDirection[0] = 0;
    randDirection[1] = 1;
    randDirection[2] = -1;
    int randChoice = r.nextInt(3);
    return randDirection[randChoice];
}

public void setXDirection(int dir) {
    xDir = dir;
}

public void setYDirection(int dir) {
    yDir = dir;
}

public void move() {
    e.ePosition.x += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()* (e.eMax_vel/2)) * xDir;
    e.ePosition.y += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()* (e.eMax_vel/2)) * yDir;
}

    public void Decider() {
    if (!decision) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int Choose = rand.nextInt(100);

        if (Choose <= 50) {
            chasing = true;
        }
        else if (Choose > 50) {
            chasing = false;
        }
        decision = true;
    }
}


    public void logicChase()  {
        Decider();
        if (!chasing) {// if not in chase mode.
            if (!moving) {// if stationary.
                if (!lock) {// if directions has not yet to be set.
                    if (counter <= 0) {// if counter has yet to be set.
                        // SET DIRECTIONS FOR X AND Y;
                        setXDirection(chooseRandomDirection());
                        setYDirection(chooseRandomDirection());
                        // SET LOCK TO TRUE
                        lock = true;
                        // SET MOVING TO TRUE
                        moving = true;
                        // SET TIME LENGTH OF ENEMY MOVEMENT
                        counter = 250;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (moving) {// if enemy is on the move.
                if (counter <= 0) {// if time counter for enemy movement has finished.
                    if (lock) {// if directions are in used.
                        // SET MOVING TO FALSE. ENEMY IS NOW RESTING
                        moving = false;
                        // SET NEW TIME COUNTER FOR ENEMY WHILE AT REST
                        counter = 500;
                        // SET LOCKS TO FALSE. DIRECTIONS ARE NOT IN USE.
                        lock = false;
                        // RANDOMIZE ENEMY MOVEMENT 
                        decision = false;
                    }
                }
                else {// ENEMY IS STILL MOVING, ENEMY IS NOW MOVING.
                    if (lock) {// IF DIRECTIONS ARE STILL LOCKED.
                        move();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else if (chasing) {

            float xdif = Math.abs(e.ePosition.x - d.dPosition.x);  <<2nd trace error
            float ydif = Math.abs(e.ePosition.y - d.dPosition.y);

            if (ydif > xdif ){
                y = e.eMax_vel;
                x = e.eMax_vel/2;
            }

            if(xdif > ydif) {
                x = e.eMax_vel;
                y = e.eMax_vel/2;
            }

            if (xdif == 0) {
                x = e.eMax_vel;
                y = 0;
            }

            if (ydif == 0) {
                y = e.eMax_vel;
                x = 0;
            }

            if (ydif == xdif) {
                y = e.eMax_vel/2;
                x = e.eMax_vel/2;
            }

            if (e.ePosition.x > d.dPosition.x)
                {x*=-1;}
            if (e.ePosition.y > d.dPosition.y)
                {y*=-1;}
            if (counter <= 0) {
                if (chasing) {//if enemy is chasing
                    if (!lock) {//lock is to check if counter has been set.
                        counter = 500;
                        lock = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        lock = false;
                        chasing = false;
                    }
                }

                else if (!chasing) {//if enemy stopped chasing
                    if (!lock) {//lock is to check if counter has been set.
                        counter = 250;
                        lock = true;
                        decision = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        lock = false;
                        chasing = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

here is the trace:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.teamkwan.dugmanalpha.level.TestLevel1$AI.logicChase(TestLevel1.java:552)
at com.teamkwan.dugmanalpha.level.TestLevel1.show(TestLevel1.java:908)
```

Line 552 is this line:

```
float xdif = Math.abs(e.ePosition.x - d.dPosition.x);
```

and both eposition and dposition are in public for referencing and they are also instantiated in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you're initializing variables `e` and `d`, `ePosition` and `dPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to step through the debugger and make sure that the methods that create `d` and `e` are being called before the methods that use `d` and `e`. Something isn't executing in the way that you think it is.

The key here is to use the debugger, so you can see things as they happen. Don't rely on reading the code and trying to execute in your head.